# I need to know the growth rate of sales in 2020 to 2021 using 2 tables on iowa_liquor_sales_forecasting dataset in google bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i'm using this query but there is no data to display. whats wrong with my query?

```sql
with t1 as
(
    select
        extract (year from date) as year,
        sum (sale_dollars) as sales_year0
    from `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales_forecasting.2020_sales_train`
    group by 1
),
t2 as
(
    select
        extract (year from date) as year,
        sum (sale_dollars) as sales_year1
    from `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales_forecasting.2021_sales_predict`
    group by 1
)
select *,
    round((sales_year1 - lag(sales_year0) over(order by t1.year asc)) / lag(sales_year0) over(order by t1.year asc) * 100,2)||'%' as growth_rate
from t1
join t2 on t1.year=t2.year
```

my expected return

```
year | total_sales | growth_rate |
2020 | ........... | ........... |
2021 | ........... | ........... |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` by itself (without left, outer, ...) in BigQuery is an [inner join](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#inner_join), which means the table on the left and the table on right have to share a condition to produce a result.

Currently, `t1` only has the year 2020 and `t2` only has the year 2021 which leads the join condition `join t2 on t1.year=t2.year` to be false.

> FROM A [INNER] JOIN B USING (x)

I guess what you want to do is to calculate the growth_rate, and below is one approach to getting the value.

```
with
t1 as (
    select
        extract (year from date) as year_2020,
        sum (sale_dollars) as sales_year_2020
    from `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales_forecasting.2020_sales_train`
    group by 1
),
t2 as (
    select
        extract (year from date) as year_2021,
        sum (sale_dollars) as sales_year_2021
    from `bigquery-public-data.iowa_liquor_sales_forecasting.2021_sales_predict`
    group by 1
)
select
    *,
    -- round((year_2021 - year_2020) / year_2020 * 100, 3) as growth_rate  -- typo (wrong column names)
    round((sales_year_2021 - sales_year_2020) / sales_year_2020 * 100, 3) as growth_rate
from t1 join t2 on t1.year_2020 = (t2.year_2021 - 1)
;
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question. but the result of growth_rate is not possible because total sales in 2020 are 396,663,131 and total sales in 2021 are 94,938,294 means that the growth rate should be negative but the result is positive 0.0495%

Comment: ohh my bad, I made a typo... I fixed the answer (and it should be -76.066%).
.

Comment: I see. thanks again for the answer. I want to ask something. What's the meaning behind -1 at (t2.year_2021 -1)?

Comment: `-1` is needed to match 2020 with 2021. So basically, the query is joining the current year with the next year by checking if year - 1 is equal to the current year.